# I have a php error and will this code perform what I want it to do once I get it working?

Tags: php, html

I have a little issue with my coding. I am trying to create 2 dropdown menus. One for displaying a list of buildings and then when user selects a building from the list, it will display the list of rooms in that building.

Problem is I have an error in my code. Below is the code:

```
      $sql="SELECT Building, Room FROM Room WHERE Building = '".$building."'";

      $sqlresult = mysql_query($sql);

      $sqldataArray = array();

      while($sqlrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlresult))
   {
      $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]; 
      $sqldataArray[$sqlrow['Building']]['Rooms'][$sqlrow['Room']]; 
   }


       $buildingHTML = ""; 
       $buildingHTML .= '<select name="buildings" id="buildingssDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $buildingHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL; 

   foreach ($sqldataArray as $building => $buildingData) {      

            $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building"'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        

            }
            $buildingHTML .= '</select>';


       $roomHTML = ""; 
       $roomHTML .= '<select name="rooms" id="roomsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
       $roomHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($buildingData['Rooms'] as $roomId => $roomData) {        

            $roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId"'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;        
  } 

            $roomHTML .= '</select>';
```

The error I am getting is this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php on line 363

This is the line of code where the error is:

```
 $buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building"'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error and will this code I have written be able to perform what I said I want the dropdown menus to perform?

Comment: You are missing a dot `.` (concatenation operator) after the first `$building`. We'll see what it does afterwards :P

Comment: Also, technically your quotes are backwards. the HTML tags want double quotes for their attributes, and you're not parsing variables inside your PHP strings anyway. i.e. `'<option value="'` is better.

Comment: why don't you just use it this way:

`$buildingHTML .= "<option value='$building'>$building</option>".PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building"'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

To:

```
$buildingHTML .= "<option value='".$building."'>" . $building . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

and change:

```
$roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId"'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

To:

```
$roomHTML .= "<option value='".$roomId."'>" . $roomId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;
```

Using consistent spacing between the concatenation operations can help make these easier to spot in the future:

```
$roomHTML .= "<option value='" . $roomId . "'>" . $roomId . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you this has solved the error and the other error which I got straight after :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your code completely or not but since the php is parses only once, you will need jquery or JavaScript in order to update the room drop down based on building selected. Google jquery dynamic dropdown box if this is what you are attempting to do.